# How to run the program in cmd after in builds with a Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, sublimetext3

I'm struggling to find a way so my `Makefile` executes the built code in `cmd` after building it I'm using `Sublime Text 3` and I'm trying to build a `c++` file with external headers.

Here is what I got (It shows the initial menu in the sublimetext "buildingresult" console):

```
function1 = Aleatori
main = main
language = g++
flags = -c

all: compile run

compile: main.o Aleatori.o #function2.o-
    $(language) $(main).o $(function1).o -o $(function1).exe

main.o: $(main).cpp
    $(language) $(flags) $(main).cpp

Aleatori.o: $(function1).cpp
    $(language) $(flags) $(function1).cpp

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.obj

.PHONY: run
run:
    ./$(function1)
```

As said it just outputs the inicial menu of the program and I can't interact with it.

```
g++ main.o Aleatori.o -o Aleatori.exe
./Aleatori
Benvingut al Brain Training Game! Si us plau, selecciona una dificultat:
1 - Facil
2 - Mig
3 - Dificil
```

Thanks for the attention. :)

Comment: Having a target like `compile:` is unusual. Normally I would expect that target to be `$(function1).exe:`.

Comment: If the program made a runnable executable the makefile usually did its job. Have you considered the possibility that there is an error on the source code?

Comment: Let me explain, the program that this makefile builds is ok, and it runs perfectly but I want the makefile to run it after it's built.

Comment: Are you on Windows?  Your makefile is creating a file `Aleatori.exe` but your `run` target is invoking a program `Aleatori`.  If you're on Windows that might work (although it's bad practice) but if you're on any POSIX system these files are not the same.

Comment: Also, please show us how you're invoking `make` (the full command line you use)

Comment: It sounds like the program you're trying to run is interactive; you can't interact with programs executed within Sublime using a standard build system.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on windows 10 64bits. @MadScientist

Comment: I'm invoking make with the default build system that comes with Sublime text. @MadScientist

Comment: Do you mean that I'll have to write a custom make build system? I have a custom one for single files in c++ but the make one is the default that comes with sublime. @OdatNurd

Comment: With the custom single file c++ build system I can build and open the program in an external cmd. That way I can freely interact with it. (That's what I want)

Comment: Yes, you need to either craft a build that opens an external console of some sort and runs the command in there, or else use some package that lets you execute commands and interact with them. [Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus) may do that for you, but I've never used it that way so I'm not sure.

Comment: Your issue is not related to make itself.  If you invoke make from a terminal then it can run a program and you can interact with it (as long as you don't build in parallel).  If you're not able to do it from some other development tool then it's an issue with that tool, not with make.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working, in case someone is interested in it:

- I deleted the "run part" of the makefile
- Made a custom make.sublime_build which runs the program after calling the "make" in cmd.
- Had to reinstall my `mingw` and install `msys2` which has a `mingw` included

make.sublime_build:

```
{
    "cmd": ["make", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/c", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:\n]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${folder:${project_path:${file_path}}}",
    "selector": "source.makefile",
    "syntax": "Packages/Makefile/Make Output.sublime-syntax",
    "keyfiles": ["Makefile", "makefile"],
    "shell": true,

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Clean",
            "shell_cmd": "make clean"
        }
    ]
}
```